# How to get a confidence measure for each prediction in a machine learning model python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict, multiclass-classification

I have the following dataframe:

```
new_df = 

BankNum   | ID    | Labels

0098-7772 | AB123 | High
0098-7772 | ED245 | High
0098-7772 | ED343 | High
0870-7771 | ED200 | Mod
0870-7771 | ED100 | Mod
0098-2123 | GH564 | Low
```

I am using scikit's `SVC` to predict the Labels `'High'`, `'Mod'`, and `'Low'`. I'm doing it as follows:

```
new_df['BankNum'] = new_df['BankNum'].map(lambda x: x.replace('-',''))
new_df['BankNum'] = new_df.BankNum.astype(np.float128)

columns =['BankNum', 'ID']
le = LabelEncoder()
new_df['ID'] = le.fit_transform(new_df.ID)

new_df['Labels'] = le.fit_transform(new_df.Labels)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(new_df[columns], new_df.Labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100., probability=True, random_state=42)

    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=8)
    print "Cross Validation Score: "
    print scores.mean()

    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
    print "Accuracy: "
    print(np.mean(predicted == y_test))
    print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))
```

I have two questions:

1.) For the classification report I'm getting a output like this:

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.00      0.00      0.00      4780
          1       0.94      1.00      0.97    104719
          2       0.00      0.00      0.00      1425

avg / total       0.89      0.94      0.92    110924
```

Why do label 0 & 2, get 0.00 precision? Can this be because of class imbalance? There are about 80893 High labels, 11798 Mod labels & 279608 Low labels. OR is SVm not a good model for this?

2.) I want to get a confidence score for each prediction. I googled and found something as follows:

```
p = clf.predict_proba( X_test )
    auc = AUC(y_test, p[:,1] )
    print "SVM AUC", auc
```

But I'm getting error: `raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_typeValueError: multiclass format is not supported`

How do I get a confidence measure for each prediction and then interpret it as well? Many thanks!!

Comment: Um, this might be a silly question, but are your features basically identifications? Is there any reason they should be correlated to your labels? Maybe that's why your results are weird. Also, make sure your svm is looking at your labels properly, not as continuous values. And doesn't it return probabilities that you can use as confidences? (Plus did you read what AUC is? How would it work in the multiclass case?)  Also, it could be class imbalance, but unless I am misunderstanding you have lots of zeros but predicted lots of ones. Maybe add more detail.